# Are there any .chm creators for OS X?

Tags: macos, chm

I'm looking for a .chm creator on Mac, but can't seem to find one? There seems to only be .chm readers for OS X.

Are there any .chm creators for OS X?

Thanks

Comment: you'll want to ask this on: http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Wajiw: I'm not so sure about how deep the avg Apple users is into CHMs. CHM's are a typical windows topic.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not, because .chm files are specific to Windows, and are deprecated even there. Are you trying to produce Apple Help files? If so, check out the [Apple Help Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/ProvidingUserAssitAppleHelp/user_help_intro/user_assistance_intro.html).

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. I'm trying to compile a help file for a Windows application. My working environment is OS X. I didn't know .chm was deprecated :( What would you recommend?

Comment: I suspect you'll have to find a Windows machine, run Parallels or VMWare, or install Windows on your Mac via Boot Camp. CHM is a very Windows thing, and it's outdated enough that there's next to no interest in Mac support.

Comment: CHM is still the only format understood by all three supported WIndows versions. XP,Vista,W7. The latter two support some newer formats, and Visual Studio is already another revision further, but CHM is still widely, widely used. If not the still the most popular.

Comment: I wouldn't quite say there's no interest in Mac support — I've come across about 5-10 CHM *readers* for OS X, though, like the OP I've yet to find a generator (to work with doxygen, for example). iChm is the best reader I've tested (mostly because its free), but there's plenty more, even a bunch on the new Mac App Store.

Comment: drdrogsplat: I'm looking for beta testers for the cmdline compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The Free Pascal compiler has a creator library, which also should work on Mac.

Note that this is just a chm compiler, iow something that compiles .html (and .hhc/.hhk/.hhp) into a .chm.

The library is already in current editions of the Free Pascal project (2.4.2). A commandline frontend (a chm compiler that understands .hhp) is currently only in development releases (but will go live in the current months in 2.4.4 and 2.6.0)

Update: the commandline compiler is now live in 2.6.0. It doesn't support all features (like merging chms)